# djongo query_set with filter on boolean field

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm, djongo

I have a django application with djongo as a database driver. My model is simple:

```
from django.db import models
from djongo.models import ObjectIdField

class TmpModel(models.Model):
    _id = ObjectIdField()
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

When I run in shell simple filter command:

```
>>> TmpModel().save()   
>>> TmpModel(is_deleted=True).save() 
>>> TmpModel.objects.filter(is_deleted=False).all()
```

I got an error:

```
(0.000) QUERY = 'SELECT "solutions_tmpmodel"."_id", "solutions_tmpmodel"."is_deleted" FROM "solutions_tmpmodel" WHERE NOT "solutions_tmpmodel"."is_deleted" LIMIT 21' - PARAMS = (); args=(); alias=default
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\test-task-YJIxAxLW-py3.10\lib\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\query.py", line 857, in parse
    return handler(self, statement)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\test-task-YJIxAxLW-py3.10\lib\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\query.py", line 933, in _select
    return SelectQuery(self.db, self.connection_properties, sm, self._params)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\test-task-YJIxAxLW-py3.10\lib\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\query.py", line 116, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\test-task-YJIxAxLW-py3.10\lib\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\query.py", line 62, in __init__
    self.parse()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\test-task-YJIxAxLW-py3.10\lib\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\query.py", line 152, in parse
    self.where = WhereConverter(self, statement)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\test-task-YJIxAxLW-py3.10\lib\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\converters.py", line 27, in __init__
    self.parse()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\test-task-YJIxAxLW-py3.10\lib\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\converters.py", line 119, in parse
    self.op = WhereOp(
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\test-task-YJIxAxLW-py3.10\lib\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\operators.py", line 476, in __init__
    self.evaluate()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\test-task-YJIxAxLW-py3.10\lib\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\operators.py", line 465, in evaluate
    op.evaluate()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\test-task-YJIxAxLW-py3.10\lib\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\operators.py", line 258, in evaluate
    self.rhs.negate()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'negate'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\test-task-YJIxAxLW-py3.10\lib\site-packages\djongo\cursor.py", line 51, in execute
    self.result = Query(
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\test-task-YJIxAxLW-py3.10\lib\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\query.py", line 784, in __init__
    self._query = self.parse()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\test-task-YJIxAxLW-py3.10\lib\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\query.py", line 885, in parse
    raise exe from e
djongo.exceptions.SQLDecodeError:

        Keyword: None
        Sub SQL: None
        FAILED SQL: SELECT "solutions_tmpmodel"."_id", "solutions_tmpmodel"."is_deleted" FROM "solutions_tmpmodel" WHERE NOT "solutions_tmpmodel"."is_deleted" LIMIT 21
        Params: ()
        Version: 1.3.6

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\test-task-YJIxAxLW-py3.10\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\test-task-YJIxAxLW-py3.10\lib\site-packages\djongo\cursor.py", line 59, in execute
    raise db_exe from e
djongo.database.DatabaseError

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\test-task-YJIxAxLW-py3.10\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 370, in __repr__
    data = list(self[: REPR_OUTPUT_SIZE + 1])
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\test-task-YJIxAxLW-py3.10\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 394, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\test-task-YJIxAxLW-py3.10\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1866, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\test-task-YJIxAxLW-py3.10\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 87, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\test-task-YJIxAxLW-py3.10\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1398, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\test-task-YJIxAxLW-py3.10\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 103, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
s.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\test-task-YJIxAxLW-py3.10\lib\site-packages\djongo\cursor.py", line 59, in execute
    raise db_exe from e
django.db.utils.DatabaseError
```

How to find out what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like an issue with Djongo's [Boolean SQL condition parsing (GitHub issue #562)](https://github.com/doableware/djongo/issues/562). For now, the solution is to use `__in` query:

```
TmpModel.objects.filter(is_deleted__in=[False]).all()
```

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed in [djongo@8587ea7](https://github.com/doableware/djongo/commit/8587ea766e4610da5f31112f7b134699e2d603ee) (as of Dec 2022, [there's no planned release](https://github.com/doableware/djongo/pull/611#issuecomment-1333968233)).

```bash
pip install git+https://github.com/doableware/djongo.git@8587ea766e4610da5f31112f7b134699e2d603ee
```

Workaround for Djongo <= 1.3.6 from [doableware/djongo#562 (comment 892486144)](https://github.com/doableware/djongo/issues/562#issuecomment-892486144):

> ```py
> from djongo.base import DatabaseWrapper
> from djongo.operations import DatabaseOperations
>
> class PatchedDatabaseOperations(DatabaseOperations):
>
>     def conditional_expression_supported_in_where_clause(self, expression):
>         return False
>
>
> DatabaseWrapper.ops_class = PatchedDatabaseOperations
> ```

Comment: Upvoted, but accepted another answer as I would avoid using not relased change.

Comment: @StuffHappens The workaround mentioned in this answer is still more appropriate than the workaround in that answer (changing all the usages, and possibly missing out in new usages).

Answer (score 0):

Use `djongo`'s model fields for all fields you have instead of `django` fields

```py
from djongo import models

class TmpModel(models.Model):
    _id = models.ObjectIdField()
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Comment: Even if I use djongo Fields the result stays the same. Still error:
 `FAILED SQL: SELECT "tasks_tmpmodel"."_id", "tasks_tmpmodel"."is_deleted" FROM "tasks_tmpmodel" WHERE NOT "tasks_tmpmodel"."is_deleted" LIMIT 21`